# Import Outlook mac archives in Windows Outlook 2010

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ms-office

How can one import Outlook mac archived files in Windows Outlook 2010? Given that the size of the archived files is 48GB, can it be done safely?? I mean NO LOSS of Data or any other files???

Comment: What did you end up doing ?

I feel all the responses related to this subject here or on reddit are just spam for this tools.

I can't find any reliable feedback of successful use of this kind of tool.

Answer (score 1):

That is one big email database archive. Moving from outlook mac to outlook windows is not possible directly as windows outlook does not support olm files. However, it can be accomplished indirectly by using IMAP to synchronize emails to a free webserver domain like yahoo, gmail etc. However, in your case, this method might not work as database size is too large. In your case, it is adviseable to utilize a third party tool like [OLM to PST Converter Pro](http://olmtopstconverter.com/) for converting OLM files into PST format compatible with Windows Outlook and later importing it into Windows. I have personally tested this utility as I was in same kindof situation a few months back adn after extensive research I zeroed on this application.